# getting NSArray objects using index numbers

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsarray

I have a array with 8 objects now and i have another array with 4 index's .I want to get objects from the first array using index values present in the second array.(objective c)

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"ECE",@"CSE",@"MECH",@"CIVIL",@"AERO",@"IT",@"EEE",@"EM"];

NSArray *indexNumberArray = @[0,2,5,7];
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: [arr objectAtIndex: [indexNumberArray objectAtIndex:0]];

Comment: i want to get 0,2,5,7 objects from the first array and store in new array !

Comment: You need to show your actual code with sufficient context to explain your question. As asked, @KKRocks answer is correct, but you have now explained that it doesn't work because the arrays are split between view controllers. Please edit your question to explain what is happening and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSArray *arr = @[@"ECE",@"CSE",@"MECH",@"CIVIL",@"AERO",@"IT",@"EEE",@"EM"];

    NSArray *indexNumberArray = @[@0,@2,@5,@7];
    NSMutableArray *arrNew = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSNumber *index in indexNumberArray) {
       [arrNew addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:[index integerValue]]];
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: not working , i have the NSArray *arr in ViewController Class and indexNumberArray in DetailViewController class.

Comment: i want to give those IndexPathArray to tableView

Comment: then what is  the problem use **arrNew** as datasource of tableview .